# GTX970 sounds likea leaf blower?

Tags: graphics-card, fan, nvidia-geforce

I have just got a new machine with the GTX970 Jetstream, it's running completely fine. My only major problem with it is the fans. It makes it sound like there is someone blowing the leafs inside the machine it's self. I have tried using MSI Afterburner and the software which comes on-disc which is Thundermaster.  On auto-settings, it shows the fan speed at 0% (i'm running with elevated permissions).. But why does it sound like a leaf blower if auto is saying 0% fan control? When over-riding this to say 100% I hear no change in the noice. Further more, all efforts currently tried to change this are failing.

What I am trying to do is to have it at a base level of quietness, but only kick the fans onto a higher setting when the GPU its self reaches a temprature set (based on user-define curves). The main complication is currently nothing I am doing is changing the overall fans?

See a picture of the card it's self below:

[image: GTX970]

Comment: You purchase a product called the Jetstream then complain bout the fan noise?  The major feature of the card itself besides being a GTX 970 is its cooling mechanic.

Comment: @ram hound I see what you're saying, but disallowing user,defined changes. Ive also found on the net stating that < 60 degrees the dual fans shouldn't rotate.. But they are constantly running

Comment: The fans are not going to stop rotating, if they did that, your GPU would overheat within seconds.  Are you using the current version of Thundermaster?

Comment: @Ramhound Indeed I am, sorry for the delay was tweaking. Contacted the company this computer was purchased from, and it turns out their advice was to check all drivers are up to date, restart the machine if it's the same. Then they are boiling it  down to a faulty board out of the batch, which does happen. the card it's self is running at 58 - 60 Decibels, which is quite loud for a card cooler to spin on idle. Even the guy I was speaking to asked to listen, he admitted that the card shouldn't be that loud at the current temprature it was running

Comment: Yes;  I would say 60Dbs is a faulty board.